# Google API creates contact, but where is it?

Tags: google-contacts-api

After lots of research and tests with a considerable variety of options, I ended up using the library below to access google contacts, because I need to create contacts:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Connection using Two Legged OAuth2 and Google Playground worked fine (I just needed to create an utilitary class that refreshes the access token), and I'm already listing the contats with success.

I have to say that I don't completely understand the results I get from contact listing compared with what I actually see when I access the contact options of my google test account, but this is a problem for another day.

The problem I need to solve quickly is to create a contact.

I've used the code present on link below:

[Google Docs Creating contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts)

Although the code performs perfectly ok (no exception is thrown and I get the new contact ID and print it on log), I'm unable to see this new contact on google account and to get it back using the listing contacts api.

Could you guys help me out with that?

Thanks and best regards,
Mauro.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed yesterday that despite the created contact wasn't showed up on "Google Contacts" web managing tool (link below), it was indeed created and stored at some place.

[Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/preview/all)

I've noticed that, when I tried to search for it.

The contact, then, was shown up as a filtered item and when I clicked on it, it was presented a contact windows with all information provided to create it.

I started to suspect that maybe it was not being shown because it doesn't belong to any group, given the fact that the contact information window has the option to add it to "My Contacts".

So, I changed my code to perform an update on just created contact adding it to "My Contacts" group and, thats it.

Now it appears correctly on google contacts managing web tool, and the only problem I still have is that the listing example that I'm using (link below) is not showing me it.

[Retrieving All Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts)

I also implemented the searching contacts with query parameters (example on the same like above), providing the same group I've used on contact's creation, like presented below:

```
Query searchQuery = new Query( getListContactsFeedURL() );
searchQuery.setStringCustomParameter( "group", 
        getMyContactsGroupEntry().getId() );
```

But it doesn't make any change on listing results.

Any thoughts?

Thanks and best regards,
Mauro.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the [Google Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) to help you get started with the Google Contacts API.

You'll need a [Google Account](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount) for testing purposes. If you already have a test account with a project registered in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console#access), then you're all set; you can visit the [Google Contacts API](https://www.google.com/contacts) user interface to set up, edit, or view your test data.

When your application requests non-public user data, it must include an access token. The token also identifies your application to Google. Use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. You must register your project in the Google API Console and enable the Contacts API service in order to use OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you said nothing that I don't know by now. I pointed out that I already have an working code for contacts listing, with access token generated through Google Playground and being refreshed without any problems. The issue is clearly pointed out on title and It's regarding the contact creation operation only. Do you have anything to contribute about that? If don't, is it possible to remove you answer (I don't know if this can be done at all) given that it could make someone bypass my question thinking that it was already answered? Thanks again.